# sql ORDER BY clause IN FOR XML

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
(SELECT t.seccolumnname 'td'
FROM   DbName.TableName t
WHERE  t.firstcolumname = 1
ORDER  BY t.seccolumnname)
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ROOT ('table')
```

It gives me an error : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

Any ideas and suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you have it in brackets? Try

```
SELECT t.seccolumnname 'td'
FROM   DbName.TableName t
WHERE  t.firstcolumnname = 1
ORDER  BY t.seccolumnname
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ROOT ('table')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason why I have brackets is because I want to give the result a name. Something like this: (SELECT t.seccolumnname 'td' 
FROM   DbName.TableName t 
WHERE  t.firstcolumnname = 1 
ORDER  BY t.seccolumnname 
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ROOT ('table') ) as XMLResult

Comment: Try `SELECT (SELECT ... FOR XML PATH('tr'), ROOT ('table'),TYPE) AS XMLResult`

Answer (score 0):

I can say that ORDER BY clause is invalid in derived tables, as you write in the script above.